# Hide text Out of TextView android Java

Tags: java, android, textview

i am a newbei when it comes to android programing.
I am trying to make a simple (for now) musicPlayer, when i show the context in LandScape, I want to animate the text from right end till the textView most left position. which is more or less center of the Screen.
I got a script to make the animation which is:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
>
</translate>
```

ok it works when it is Portrait, cause i am using the TextView on Top of the Screen from right to left, so the text can slide on the whole screen.
Now when it comes to LandScape, as i said before i dont want the text to slide through whole screen.

what i want to do is when it reaches the textView's most left Position, it should start disapear ...

Any Help ...
Please

Comment: You can use yourTextView.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE)

Comment: help is appreciated, but i dont want to make it disappear. i just dont want to show it out of textView, because it has an infinite circle. whenever it get out of the screen 100% it comes in from right side again

Answer (score 0):

> what i want to do is when it reaches the textView's most left
>   Position, it should start disapear ...

To achieve this, you could add an alpha transition to your translate animation, which will cause the text to fade out as it approaches the left most position. It would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />

<alpha
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

And if you don't want it to start fading out until it gets closer to the edge, you can add an offset to the alpha block like this:

`android:startOffset="200"`

That will cause the alpha animation to not start until the time in the argument has elapsed (200ms in the case above).

Comment: thanks, it works partly (probably i am not using it the way it should be). if fades out, but now what. shall I use the alpha process again, to fade it in before it comes in the screen

Comment: Before the animation begins, you could call `setAlpha(1.0)` on the `TextView` to reset the value. I think that should work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: there is on problem, when it starts fadeout i goes with the whole text (content of textView) i need to make it letter by letter, as it goes out of the textView

Comment: Naaah, it never comes back

Answer (score 0):

if we put this code in the layout file it works perfectly.

```
android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

AnyWayThanksForYourHelp